# PL/SQL Packages and Procedures

Tags: plsql, package, procedure, sys-refcursor

I'm trying to use a procedure within a package so that I can call in in an external program. I keep getting a encountered the symbol "CREATE" error. I've tried a lot of different ways of doing it so I'm sorry if my code is messy, I'm really lost with this one

```
create or replace package GetAllCust as
function GeTAllCust return sys_refcursor;

procedure GET_ALLCUST_FROM_DB(pSysRefCur OUT sys_refcursor);
end GetAllCust;

create or replace package body GetAllCust as
procedure GET_ALLCUST_FROM_DB (pSysRefCur OUT sys_refcursor) as
begin
    open pSysRefCur for select * from customer;
    return pSysRefCur;
exception
    when others then
        raise_application_error(-20000, SQLERRM);
end GET_ALLCUST_FROM_DB;
 end GetAllCust;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined function `GeTAllCust` in package specification, however in body it is not specified.
And another error was return statement in procedure body which is not required.

Try creating your package and package body as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE GetAllCust
AS
   FUNCTION GeTAllCust
      RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR;

   PROCEDURE GET_ALLCUST_FROM_DB (pSysRefCur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);
END GetAllCust;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY GetAllCust
AS
   FUNCTION GeTAllCust
      RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
   AS
      p_cursor   SYS_REFCURSOR;
   BEGIN
      OPEN p_cursor FOR SELECT * FROM customer;

      RETURN p_cursor;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
      THEN
         raise_application_error (-20001, SQLERRM);
   END GeTAllCust;

   PROCEDURE GET_ALLCUST_FROM_DB (pSysRefCur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
   AS
   BEGIN
      OPEN pSysRefCur FOR SELECT * FROM customer;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         raise_application_error (-20000, SQLERRM);
   END GET_ALLCUST_FROM_DB;
END GetAllCust;
/
```

Comment: I tried your code and I'm still getting a encountered the symbol "CREATE"

Comment: @BrendonRother Which version of `SQLDeveloper` are you using?

Comment: @BrendonRother I have updated my answer. When you run from `SQLDeveloepr` you add `/` at the end package specification and package body.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much, I've been using the / but I didn't think to use it for a package

Comment: @BrendonRother Glad to know that you have resolved your errors.

Answer (score 0):

To analyze these problems, execute `SHOW ERROR` after compliling the package, this will show you the problems:

```
Warning: compiled but with compilation errors
Errors for PACKAGE BODY GETALLCUST

LINE/COL ERROR                                                            
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
5/5      PLS-00372: In a procedure, RETURN statement cannot contain an exp

5/5      PL/SQL: Statement ignored                                        
2/10     PLS-00323: subprogram or cursor 'GETALLCUST' is declared in a pac
         kage specification and must be defined in the package body
```

So there are two problems:

1. You are trying to return a value from a procedure. This is only valid for functions.
2. You define the function `GeTAllCust` in your package header, but do not implement it in the body

Comment: Thanks Peter just having some trouble getting show error to output the same amount of detail that you've shown, It's simply outputting the same error I was getting. I'm using Oracle SQL Developer if that makes a difference

Comment: To see the errors in SQL Developer, try to execute both the `CREATE`-statement and the `SHOW ERROR` at once, using `F5`. [Viewing PLSQL Compilation Errors in Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/01/viewing-plsql-compilation-errors-in-oracle-sql-developer/) provides more information.